# Permission issues with Capistrano and Symfony3

Tags: apache, symfony, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my symfony app with capistrano but i'm stuck with a permission issue...

Here is my deploy.rb:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.0"

set :application, "projetLavande-api"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:me/project-api.git"

set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :info


set :composer_install_flags, '--no-dev --optimize-autoloader'

set :file_permissions_users, ["www-data"]
set :file_permissions_paths, ["var"]

set :linked_dirs, ["var"]

before "deploy:updated", "deploy:set_permissions:acl"
after 'deploy:updated', 'symfony:cache:clear'
```

The deployment is OK, capi executes the commande setfacl:

`/usr/bin/env setfacl -Rn -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:me:rwX /var/www/project/shared/var`

But Apache can not create a directory in the `var/cache`

Any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with a setfacl to the whole application directory, like:

```
 $HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

 $sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`myuser`:rwX /var/www/project
 $sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`myuser`:rwX /var/www/project
```

Answer (score 1):

During your deployment, you may have your var/cache folder deleted. It might be recreated with wrong right access. Try to launch this task too :

```
/usr/bin/env setfacl -dRn -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:me:rwX /var/www/project/shared/var
```

The -d means "default", so all new files and folders will inheri of these default rights.

EDIT : http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd